# How to call a MainActivity method from ViewHolder in RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-bluetooth, android-viewholder

In [a simple app project at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q39/QR_BT_Pairing) I have only 2 custom Java-files:

1. [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q39/QR_BT_Pairing/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/qr_bt_pairing/MainActivity.java) contains Bluetooth- and UI-related source code
2. [DeviceListAdapter.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q39/QR_BT_Pairing/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/qr_bt_pairing/DeviceListAdapter.java) contains an `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` for displaying Bluetooth devices in a `RecyclerView`

[image: app screenshot]

The [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q39/QR_BT_Pairing/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/qr_bt_pairing/MainActivity.java) contains a method to be called, when user taps on a Bluetooth device in the `RecyclerView`:

```
public void confirmConnection(String address) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to pair to " + device + "?");
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            device.createBond();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
    builder.show();
}
```

And in the `ViewHolder` class (in the [DeviceListAdapter.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q39/QR_BT_Pairing/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/qr_bt_pairing/DeviceListAdapter.java)) the  click listener is defined:

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends
  RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

  protected static class ViewHolder
        extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView deviceAddress;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String address = deviceAddress.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                "How to call MainActivity.confirmConnection(address)?",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
```

**My problem:**

How to call `confirmConnection(address)` method from `ViewHolder`s `onClick` method?

I keep moving `ViewHolder` class declaration between the 2 Java files and also tried putting it into its own file - and just can't find the right way.

Should I maybe add a field to `ViewHolder` class and (when?) store a reference to `MainActivity` instance there?

**UPDATE:**

This works for me, but seems to be a workaround (and also I was thinking of using `LocalBroadcastReceiver` - which would be an even more hackish workaround) -

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String address = deviceAddress.getText().toString();

        try {
            ((MainActivity) v.getContext()).confirmConnection(address);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your ViewHolder contains a View. This View has a Context. This Context is most probably your activity. So cast the Context to MainActivity and you should be fine. Using interfaces is the better approach though. ((MainActivity)v.getContext()).confirmConnection() should be it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To keep your classes decoupled, I'd suggest defining an interface on your adapter, something like:

```
public interface OnBluetoothDeviceClickedListener {
    void onBluetoothDeviceClicked(String deviceAddress);
}
```

Then add a setter for this in your adapter:

```
private OnBluetoothDeviceClickedListener mBluetoothClickListener;

public void setOnBluetoothDeviceClickedListener(OnBluetoothDeviceClickedListener l) {
    mBluetoothClickListener = l;
}
```

Then internally, in your `ViewHolder`'s `onClick()`:

```
if (mBluetoothClickListener != null) {
    final String addresss = deviceAddress.getText().toString();
    mBluetoothClickListener.onBluetoothDeviceClicked(address);
}
```

Then just have your `MainActivity` pass in a listener to the `Adapter`:

```
mDeviceListAdapter.setOnBluetoothDeviceClickedListener(new OnBluetoothDeviceClickedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBluetoothDeviceClicked(String deviceAddress) {
        confirmConnection(deviceAddress);
    }
});
```

This way you can reuse the adapter later without it being tied to that particular behavior.

Comment: What if I'm getting an "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error?

Comment: @user3484582 Probably means you're trying to call a method in the enclosing class from a static inner class (e.g. if you have a static inner class in your Activity and are trying to call a method on your Activity from there)

Comment: How can mBluetoothClickListener non static field be used in static ViewHolder class?

Comment: @MBDevelop, I wrote an answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40563598/2914140.

Answer (score 7):

For those who are looking for invoking a callback from a static ViewHolder do the following.
Let you have an adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final int resource;
    private final List<Item> items;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    ...
    private Callback callback;

    private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onImageClick(int position);
        void onRemoveItem(int position);
    }
}
```

Then you should add a setCallback method and call it from activity/fragment. Also you shouldn't make a callback static (it may lead to problems when you use the same adapter in many classes). You should create a field inside the ViewHolder. So:

```
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items, Callback callback) {
        super();
        this.resource = resource;
        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
        final Item item = this.items.get(position);
        viewHolder.caption.setText(item.caption);
        viewHolder.callback = callback;
    }

    // A method to set a callback from activity/fragment.
    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public static class Item {
        public long id;
        public String number;
        public String caption;

        ...
    }

    private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected final TextView caption;
        // A reference to an adapter's callback.
        protected Callback callback;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.caption = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.caption);
        }

        private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                if (id == R.id.image) {
                    // Invoke the callback here.
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback.onImageClick(getLayoutPosition());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

After you have made the adapter you can invoke it so:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item,
        new ArrayList<MyAdapter.Item>(), null);

adapterListener = new MyAdapter.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onImageClick(int position) {
        // Some actions.
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveItem(int position) {
        // Some actions.
    }
};

adapter.setCallback(adapterListener);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the MainActivity as a constructor-parameter for the Adapter and store it in a field. Or you use a event-bus - there are multiple ways to do it - I would go for the field

Answer (score 2):

In your adapter, create an interface that will provide a callback to the main activity

```
public interface MyCallback{
    void onItemClicked();
}

private MyCallback listener;

public setOnItemClickListener(MyCallback callback){
    listener = callback;
}
```

Have your main activity implement it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyCallback
```

then implement the callback

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(){
    //do work
}
```

then just set the callback from the adapter

```
mDeviceListAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call Activity method by using instance of Activity like this, inside MainActivity write below code

```
mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

Inside Adapter

```
 private MainActivity _mainActivity;
 public DeviceListAdapter(MainActivity activity){
 this._mainActivity=activity;
 }
```

Inside your onClick method

```
 _mainActivity.yourActivityMethod(address);
```