# how to add scrollview dynamically to dynamic table rows

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-tablelayout

I am new to android.I have table layout in XML and dynamically adding rows,i am trying to put dynamic rows into scrollview.please anyone help how to do.

Here my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    <include layout="@layout/header"
        android:id="@+id/header" />
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="#deb8"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Please Confirm the Quote and check for Errors "/>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_message" >
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tv_message"
        android:id="@+id/table_orderfulfillment"
        android:stretchColumns="*">


              </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</Relative Layout>
```

Comment: Instead of using a TableLayout, you could use a RecyclerView as a Grid to show information and customize the item layout. See good example here: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html

Comment: Good example here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have tried to Populate Tablelayout dynamically through String Array

here is the code: scrollview is also added.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] row = { "ROW1", "ROW2", "Row3", "Row4", "Row 5", "Row 6",
                         "Row 7"
                       };
        String[] column = { "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3", "COLUMN4",
                            "COLUMN5", "COLUMN6"
                          };
        int rl=row.length;
        int cl=column.length;

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        TableLayout tableLayout = createTableLayout(row, column,rl, cl);
        HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

        hsv.addView(tableLayout);
        sv.addView(hsv);
        setContentView(sv);

    }

    private TableLayout createTableLayout(String [] rv, String [] cv,int rowCount, int columnCount)
    {
        // 1) Create a tableLayout and its params
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        // 2) create tableRow params
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        tableRowParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        tableRowParams.weight = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            // 3) create tableRow
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

            for (int j= 0; j < columnCount; j++)
            {
                // 4) create textView
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                //  textView.setText(String.valueOf(j));
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
                String s2 = Integer.toString(j);
                String s3 = s1 + s2;
                int id = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                Log.d("TAG", "-___>"+id);
                if (i ==0 && j==0)
                {
                    textView.setText("0==0");
                }
                else if(i==0)
                {
                    Log.d("TAAG", "set Column Headers");
                    textView.setText(cv[j-1]);
                }
                else if( j==0)
                {
                    Log.d("TAAG", "Set Row Headers");
                    textView.setText(rv[i-1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    textView.setText(""+id);
                    // check id=23
                    if(id==23)
                    {
                        textView.setText("ID=23");

                    }
                }

                // 5) add textView to tableRow
                tableRow.addView(textView, tableRowParams);
            }

            // 6) add tableRow to tableLayout
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, tableLayoutParams);
        }

        return tableLayout;
    }
}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to load more data on scroll.!

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                                     int newState) {

                        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                        // If scroll state is touch scroll then set userScrolled
                        // true
                        if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                            userScrolled = true;

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx,
                                           int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                        // Here get the child count, item count and visibleitems
                        // from layout manager

                        visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                        pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager
                                .findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                        // Now check if userScrolled is true and also check if
                        // the item is end then update recycler view and set
                        // userScrolled to false
                        if (userScrolled
                                && (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) == totalItemCount) {
                            userScrolled = false;

                            RefreshData(oldestPostId);


                            //  implementScrollListener();
                        }

                    }

                });
```