# CardView Strange Behaviour

Tags: android, view, background, android-cardview, elevation

I have a simple layout with CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cv_tag"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="@dimen/tag_height"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:clickable="true"
app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_selection_indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/PrimaryWhiteText.Tiny"
        tools:text="Hard"/>

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And it's rendering not as I expect it to. It looks like system wraps this layout into FrameLayout with elevation and white background. Interesting thing is if I wrap this layout into FrameLayout by myself elevation goes away but white background is still there (Background of frame layout not CardView)

[image: White background]
[image: Elevation]

How to remove elevation and white background and why is it happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You actually do have elevation `app:cardElevation="2dp"`

Comment: some time back i also face same problem. In my case its due to         android:hardwareAccelerated="false" this property in menifest file

Comment: hope this will help you....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407057/android-onclick-inside-gridview-row/44407767?noredirect=1#comment75815533_44407767

Comment: @IvBaranov it's card's elevation and should affect only cardview (colored part) but not its background (white part)

Comment: @PankajSharma this property in manifest removed elevation but on all views (( so it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814885/6017529)

My latout is for custom view and when I add setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)); to its contructors elevation and white background have gone.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a quirk of pre-API 21 implementation.

In the mean time, you probably don't need the CardView altogether. Consider using DrawableResource.

Refer to [How do I set the rounded corner radius of a color drawable using xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122199/how-do-i-set-the-rounded-corner-radius-of-a-color-drawable-using-xml#2123712)

**Old answer:**

By default CardView has a background color set depending on your theme.
Here's an exempt from styles

```
<color name="cardview_dark_background">#FF424242</color>
<color name="cardview_light_background">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

And from the initialization of the view

```
if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.CardView_cardBackgroundColor)) {
            backgroundColor = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.CardView_cardBackgroundColor);
} else {
     // There isn't one set, so we'll compute one based on the theme
     final TypedArray aa = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(COLOR_BACKGROUND_ATTR);
     final int themeColorBackground = aa.getColor(0, 0);
     aa.recycle();

     // If the theme colorBackground is light, use our own light color, otherwise dark
     final float[] hsv = new float[3];
     Color.colorToHSV(themeColorBackground, hsv);
     backgroundColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(hsv[2] > 0.5f
                    ? getResources().getColor(R.color.cardview_light_background)
                    : getResources().getColor(R.color.cardview_dark_background));
 }
```

To change the color, use the `app:cardBackgroundColor` attribute

Comment: Actually, I'm changing card background color with 'app:cardBackgroundColor' and its working goog (you can see colored part of view). But the problem is that it's look like the system wraps my layout inside another frame layout with elevation and white background. And if I wrap this layout in frame layout by myself elevation goes away but the white background is still there (I mean white background of Frame Layout not CardView).

Comment: @OlexiiMuraviov It's definitely not FrameLayout's white background, since it doesn't have rounded corners by default.

It would help if you told us what API level does your device have, since there are different implementations of CardView used for pre-21 and pre-17.
Also, see new edit for an alternative.

If nothing helps, you may dump XML hierarchy with Android Device Monitor and post it here.

Comment: I have solved this issue. Found answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810447/cardview-corner-background-not-transparent . Thank you for your efforts! My layout is a custom view and when I set in its constructors setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)) elevation and white background have gone.

Comment: Yea, that answer makes sense, considering how it works across different versions of Android.
Thanks for the follow-up!