# Xml card layout

Tags: java, android, xml

i trying to get a layout just like the image below for a game in android studio

[image]

currently my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dreacot.testmymemory.Game">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backside"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="136dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backside"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="156dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="136dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backside"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="266dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="136dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backside"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="53dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="285dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backside"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="156dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="285dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backside"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="266dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="285dp" />
```

i want more cards to be added on the next level eg lvl 2
do i need to make several layouts for each level?

also i want each card to show its face when it is clicked

and finally i feel i am not doing the right thing as i feel xml files cannot be called into the gameplay is there a better way to do this layout(maybe programmatically)?

could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it programmatically.

**1.** Use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` to show your card as grid style.

**2.** Create a layout with just a `CardView` with single `ImageView` for your single card item.

**3.** Create an custom `RecyclerView.Adapter<>` and use it with `RecyclerView` to populate your card data on `CardView`.

**4.** Add `onItemClick` listener to `Adapter` to flip to the specific `Card` item and do something as per your needs.

Here are some useful links about `RecyclerView`:

1. [Android RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager Example](http://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example)
2. [Android GridLayoutManager with RecyclerView in Material Design](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)
3. [Simple Android grid example using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)

Here is a good [library](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) for `CardView` animation.

Hope this will help~

Comment: when the card flips i want to show different items on each card, and if i populate i would populate about 32 cards, so how do i do this and display 32 different items on each card flip

Comment: You can do everything. You can set any image on card view. If you want to show different layout for other side then you have to design another layout.

Comment: alright from your answer things have cleared up really well and i understand what to do know, but i see lots of issues as i go on because i dont think you really get the picture i am trying to paint, but you answer helps

Comment: You can use this library for card flip animation>> https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: lets talk in chat  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146202/discussion-between-fat-and-kennedy

Comment: im stuck at number 3

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Comment: just did, but most of the tutorials out there deal with text like this one, how do i populate a single image

Comment: 1. Add an imageview in your layout. 2. Inn your adapter viewholder add the imageview. 3. In onBindViewHolder change the image on imageview as per needs

Comment: have you tried the tutorial that i mentioned in my answer? These tutorial contains about how to populate image on imageview. See again and read thoroughly. >>>> http://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example   >>>> https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it is not the proper way to do it, In this way maybe you can achieve this for 6 cards. What if you have let's say 100 cards or may be 1000, will you add 100 images in Layout and get reference of 100 images in Activity and set Click Listeners and animations to turn the side on 100 images?

Use "GridView" and Adapter for your views, it will do your work with ease.

Check this:  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Thank You i certainly wouldn't want 100 onclick listeners