# Adding link to open site in android recycler grid layout

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

Have created a grid layout using recycler .The grid as many site icon(images)how can i connect the images to  specific links for website .Please assist...i shall be glad for your response.step by step since am new please.In shot to open website on image click.

Comment: Make some ImageButton that launch an Activity with a WebView : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Comment: i used recycler not web view

Comment: Have u checked link and it's answer ?

Comment: i want to connect image button to specific website.have many site images remember.

Comment: yes many buttons with no links joining site.heve seen the code

Comment: You will not get same code any where. you have to combine from different sources.

Answer (score 0):

After onclick, load website URL in custom chrome tabs
[Custom Chrome Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

Comment: its not helpful too.i need a more simpler explanation and example..ie have facebook image,twiter,stackoverflow.i can i connet this image to link in recycler.

Comment: Please explain in detail, what you want to achieve