# ListView items Vertical Orientation [XML]

Tags: android, xml

How to do two items  in one line but at the same time items should to be in one ListView and have one Adapter :

**My example [now] :**

- [Item style (github)](https://github.com/sanke46/E-Commerce/blob/add_sqllite_in_app/app/src/main/res/layout/list.xml)
- [ListView (github)](https://github.com/sanke46/E-Commerce/blob/add_sqllite_in_app/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_listview_1.xml)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **RecyclerView** instead of ListView and set GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView.

Comment: just a minut, I wiil try

Comment: @IlyaFedoseev GridLayoutManager. Here is how you can implement it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40587168/2528967