# Displaying a Matrix

Tags: android

I've got a task to display N*N matrix in Android app.

Numbers in this matrix should be in the specific order, like this: 
[matrix example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpMAl.png)

The main trouble is that i should display each cell of matrix with animation with some delay (matrix shouldn't be visible at first and then cells appear, one by one).

How can i achieve this kind of effect? Should I use GridView with custom adapter, or I should create my own view by extending "View" class? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how large your matrix will get but I'd recommend you implement this using a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`, especially if your grid matrix may have variable number of elements.

In a simplified overview, you can achieve this by creating a `RecyclerView` in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then in your the `Activity`, apply the `GridLayoutManager` to this `RecyclerView` which will place each cell (which you will also need to define using a layout and inflating it in the `RecyclerView`'s `onBind` method) in a grid layout as you'd like.

**I suggest you see this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587169/394933) that explains pretty much exactly how to achieve this.**

For animations, you can get access to each cell's `View` via the `RecyclerView.Adapter` that you will define (see the aforementioned post). You probably will want to start each cell with `visibility` set to `gone` or `invisible` then reveal them however you'd like.

If you know your grid size is fixed and relatively small, you could still use a `GridLayout` which will spare you all the adapter code for `RecyclerView`.

Let me know if you're still having trouble understanding, hope this helps!