# How can i speed up the activity start with a lot Views in Android?

Tags: android, performance

I have a tabbed activity with 6 tabs. It's a lotto ticket picker. I created the grid like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the). Every grid has 90 generetad TextViews. The activity start in 2-3 seconds.

[image: Grid]

Comment: You could do heavy stuff in a separate thread.

Comment: Is it possible that to move the other fragment creation in the background? with asynctask? or just delayed them? and if yes how?

Comment: You can use lazy loading with RecyclerView + GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

You can do heavy stuff in a thread.
In your onCreate method:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //do heavy work here
        final int result=42;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //call methods of your views here.
                textView.setText(result +"");
            }
        });
    }
};
t.start();
```