# onNestedScroll not called using custom BottomNavigationViewBehavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I want to implement a hide on scroll `BottomNavigationView`. Googled around for solutions as there doesn't seem to exist one provided by android framework, that would work out of the box and my current setup is following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`MainActivity`:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) bottomNavigation.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationViewBehavior());
```

`BottomNavigationViewBehavior`:

```
public class BottomNavigationViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

    private int height;

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, int layoutDirection) {
        height = child.getHeight();
        return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                   BottomNavigationView child, @NonNull
                                           View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target,
                                   int axes, int type) {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, 
    @NonNull BottomNavigationView child,
                           @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
                           int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed,
                           @ViewCompat.NestedScrollType int type) {
        if (dyConsumed > 0) {
            slideDown(child);
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
            slideUp(child);
        }
    }

    private void slideUp(BottomNavigationView child) {
        child.clearAnimation();
        child.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(200);
    }

    private void slideDown(BottomNavigationView child) {
        child.clearAnimation();
        child.animate().translationY(height).setDuration(200);
    }
}
```

The `onLayoutChild` is called everytime, the parent is `CoordinatorLayout` and child is `BottomNavigationView`. But the `onStartNestedScroll` and `onNestedScroll` is never called, so the bottom navigation view don't get hidden on scroll. Tried switching the layouts around - fragment, no fragment, tried setting the bahavior through xml layout, nothing worked. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue :(

Answer (score -1):

Your xml should look something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
        app:layout_behavior="BottomNavigationViewBehavior ">
    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And ditch this part:

```
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) bottomNavigation.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationViewBehavior());
```

You have a similar example [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons#animating-the-floating-action-button)

P.S. You should also change the GridView and use a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager instead like you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)