# how to create recycler-view card-view grid layout like attached screenshot

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a android app where i need to display blog post in recycler-view / card-view grid like attached any examples or suggestion?

[image]

or like this one

[image]

or like this ?

[image]

Comment: using recyclerview use GridViewLayout in it it will help for 3rd screenshot

Comment: @AbhinavGupta any example would help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40587168/7319704  use this link

Answer (score 0):

[Grid View Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XecTI.jpg)

I hope this screenshot of my app is a bit close to what you want as shown in your 3rd screenshot. I will show you my source code just for you get an idea.

**LAYOUT.XML File** This is the layout File

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layer"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addBttn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/doneBttn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"/>
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:layout_below="@id/layer"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>**
```

**This is the ADAPTER Class used to fill in the data to GridView**

**Then you can set the Adapter created to your grid view like this from any of your Activities**

```
public class gridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private View view;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private final ArrayList<Uri> Images;

public gridViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context,ArrayList<Uri>images) {
    this.context = context;
    Images = images;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Images.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView == null) {
        view = new View(context);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout,null);
        ImageView imageView =     (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageURI(Images.get(position));

    }
    return view;
}
```

}

```
gridView =(GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridViewAdapter gridAdapter = new gridViewAdapter(this,imgUriList);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```