# How to make a Level Menu - Android

Tags: android, android-studio

StackOverflow community,

I'm currently programming an Android game,
I have a ListView, with the level display,
but this looks quite normal,
I would like to make her look like in the picture, I just have no idea how? :D

[Level Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq6zE.png)

Please help.

Best regards Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GridLayout Manager, here is an example of how to implement it [Simple Android grid example using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager (like the old GridView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)

Comment: If this was useful, can you please mark as a correct answer?