# Android Gridlayout takes too much time to initialize

Tags: android, performance, loader, android-gridlayout

I have a really long onActivityCreated for one of my fragments because it has to initialize a big gridlayout. Instead of using xml, I did it programmatically because it is easier on my life to code than to create 108 separate views using xml. The only problem: it takes forever to load everything when the fragment is created.

I have tried to use AsyncTaskLoader and that didn't work because you can't change a view using a different thread. Please tell me anyway I can make it run faster or better. This is my first app, so there is a good chance I am just being really dumb. Any help is appreciated.

Also I am doing many things in this fragment, like using mediaplayers and using onclicklisteners. All that works perfectly, its just really slow to make the fragment load. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textTranslation, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
        GridLayout gridLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
        final MediaPlayer[] sound_resource = {MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.a_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.b_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.c_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.d_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.e_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.f_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.g_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.h_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.i_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.j_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.k_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.l_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.m_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.n_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.o_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.p_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.q_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.r_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.s_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.t_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.u_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.v_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.w_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.x_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.y_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.z_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.one_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.two_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.three_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.four_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.five_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.six_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.seven_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.eight_sound), MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.nine_sound),
                MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), R.raw.zero_sound)};

        String abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        List<ImageButton> imageButtonList = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();

        final IsPlaying isPlaying = new IsPlaying(null);

        final int[] ind = {0};

        for (int i = 0, c = 0, r = 0; i < 36 * 3; i++, c++) {
            if (c == 3) {
                c = 0;
                r++;
                ind[0] = r;
            }

            GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(r, GridLayout.CENTER);
            GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.spec(c, GridLayout.CENTER);
            GridLayout.Spec col2 = GridLayout.spec(c, GridLayout.LEFT);

            GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);

            if (c == 0) {
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(v.getContext());
                imageButton.setId(ind[0]);
                imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_sound);
                imageButtonList.add(imageButton);
                imageButtonList.get(ind[0]).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        MediaPlayer player = sound_resource[v.getId()];
                        if (!isPlaying.somethingIsPlaying) {//if nothing is playing
                            player.start();
                            isPlaying.mediaPlayer = player;
                            isPlaying.somethingIsPlaying = true;
                        } else if (player.isPlaying()) {//if something is playing and player is already playing
                            player.seekTo(0);
                            player.start();
                        } else {//if something is playing and player is not playing
                            isPlaying.mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                            isPlaying.mediaPlayer.pause();
                            player.start();
                            isPlaying.mediaPlayer = player;
                            isPlaying.somethingIsPlaying = true;
                        }

                        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                isPlaying.somethingIsPlaying = false;
                                mp.seekTo(0);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                gridLayout.addView(imageButton, layoutParams);
            } else if (c == 1) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(v.getContext());
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(abc.charAt(r)));
                textView.setTextSize(27);
                textView.setTextColor(v.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.main_text_color));
                textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                gridLayout.addView(textView, layoutParams);

            } else if (c == 2) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(v.getContext());
                imageView.setImageResource(images_resources[r]);

                GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col2);
                layoutParams1.leftMargin = 13;
                gridLayout.addView(imageView, layoutParams1);
            }
        }

    }
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom adapter class to create views.

Take hint from the following link...

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a Recycler View as a Grid view and by creating your custom Recycler View Adapter. I think it will work fast as the Recycler view only creates the cells that are visible on the screen with a little offset.

You can get help on Grid view with Recycler view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the) .