# Android most efficient Table Layout

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-tablelayout

So I have a few arrays of data I would like to display in an activity without having like 15 text views with unique ids. Is there a code efficient way to make a Table layout or something like it where I could feed in data and it would automatically place it in there respective text views? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve that by using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#top_of_page) (with a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)). Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587169/7972851) answer.

If there are only `TextViews` and you don't want a specific layout you can use [SimpleAdapter](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingSimpleAdaptertofilldatatoListView.htm), if you want to modify the layout you have to extend RecycleView.Adapter (there is an example in the answer above).

You can add/remove items into/from a List and use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) that

> can calculate the difference between two lists and output a list of update operations that converts the first list into the second one.

There are a lot of tutorials about using this class. Have a look [here](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00) or [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/smart-way-to-update-recyclerview-using-diffutil-345941a160e0).

Or you can use the `notifyItemChanged()` method:

> If the list needs an update, call a notification method on the
>   RecyclerView.Adapter object, such as notifyItemChanged(). The layout
>   manager then rebinds any affected view holders, allowing their data to
>   be updated.

**LE:** There are some libraries available. Here is a list:

1. https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView
2. https://github.com/HYY-yu/TableRecyclerView
3. https://github.com/Cleveroad/AdaptiveTableLayout
4. https://github.com/celerysoft/TableFixHeaders