# Displaying Images In A ScrollView?

Tags: android, image, scroll, scrollview

I am trying to make an app where, there are two rows of images and you have to scroll down to view the rest. So like pictures in the picture app on your phone.

I tried using the Scroll View, when I created a new project in Android Studio, but it gave me a large action bar and a mail icon on the view.

All I want is to have no action bar, and images that are scroll able. Should I use a different View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `RecyclerView`. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

with GridLayout -> [Simple Android grid example using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager (like the old GridView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)

But your real problem I recon would be to download the images from somewhere. I suggest `Picasso` or `Glide`

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `res\styles` and open `styles.xml` 
Change your app's parent theme to something like ...`NoActionBar` :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Now the `Actionbar` is removed and you can use the `ScrollView`.