# How to center imageView in third row using Constraint Layout

Tags: android, centering, android-constraintlayout

[2x2 plus 1 un-centered tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhlmX.png)

I have 5 square tiles all of which need to be the same size but flexible so it can grow and shrink to fit different display sizes.  There is text beneath each tile.  I want the last row to be centered horizontally and wish to do this using only xml if possible.  I also have a toolbar and a navigation bar.  Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" android:background="@drawable/sunrise" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/toolBarColor"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/refresh2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Now - The Technology"
        android:textColor="@color/appTitleColor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPlay"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/play"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/con_des_play"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivReminder"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvPlay"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivPlay"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivPlay"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivPlay"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:text="@string/play_10_minutes"
          android:textColor="@color/iconTextColor"
          android:textSize="16sp"
/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivReminder"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/reminder"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/con_des_play"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPlay"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvReminder"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivReminder"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivReminder"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivReminder"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:text="@string/now_reminder"
          android:textColor="@color/iconTextColor"
          android:textSize="16sp"
/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGuide"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/guide"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/con_des_play"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPlay"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivPlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivPlay"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvGuide"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivGuide"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivGuide"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivGuide"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:text="@string/guide"
          android:textColor="@color/iconTextColor"
          android:textSize="16sp"
/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivUpgrade"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/upgrade"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/con_des_play"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivGuide"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivReminder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivReminder"

/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvUpgrade"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivUpgrade"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivUpgrade"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivUpgrade"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:text="@string/upgrade"
          android:textColor="@color/iconTextColor"
          android:textSize="16sp"
/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLearn"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/learn"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/con_des_play"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvGuide"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivGuide"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivGuide"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvLearn"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvLearn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivLearn"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivLearn"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivLearn"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
          android:text="@string/learn"
          android:textColor="@color/iconTextColor"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D3D3D3"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" app:itemTextColor="@color/navAccent" style="@style/AppTheme"
        android:visibility="visible" app:itemIconTint="@color/navAccent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: used GridLayout manger into recyclerview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I tried the minimal app mentioned above and it works, only I want the last row centered if there aren't as many columns as in the row above.  I tried using android:layout_gravity="center" and layout:gravity="center" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try change attributes of `android:id="@+id/ivLearn"`

from

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivGuide"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivGuide"
```

to

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Comment: That didn't quite work.  It made one huge icon at the bottom and 4 small ones above it.  I need the image views to all be the same size.

Comment: can you set explicit dimensions for ivLearn? for example, instead `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_height="0dp` set `150dp` size

Comment: If I did that then the images wouldn't automatically adjust for different screen sizes.  Perhaps there is a way to use guidelines to achieve the result.

Comment: I got it to work by setting a vertical guideline to 25% and another one to 67% and set constraints based on these guidelines.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but the recycler view looks like the best and most flexible answer from the android team.  I used vertical guidelines using percentages and I need to test it on different screen sizes which seems to work at least on one screen size.  I will have to convert the Java code to Kotlin which I am learning as well.

Thanks.