# GridView isn't creating Squares

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create a simple android wallpaper app just for practice.
So I added pictures to an assets folder, and I want to show them in a gridview.
I created it, but for some reason the pictures in the gridview doesn't appear in squares rather in a large height format.
I'm attaching my code if anyone can see where the problem is:

this is how it looks like:

[image]

you can see that it creates rectangles instead of equal squares.

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
```

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private String[] list;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
    try {
        list = context.getAssets().list("imgs");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int getCount() {return list.length;}
public Object getItem(int position) {return null;}
public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView img;
    if (convertView == null) {
        img = new ImageView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        img.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(params));
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        img.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        img = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    try {
        InputStream ims = context.getAssets().open("imgs/" + list[position]);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return img;
 }
}
```

and this is the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your image size is not fixed even `GridView` is not the best approach try using `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`  refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Comment: Change `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` to LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(item_size, item_size);

Comment: @AkshayKatariya it is not about RecycleView or GridView

Answer (score 0):

@TheDragoner Your gridview is using Wrap Content as its Layout Params i.e.  `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

As a result it the grid takes the actual image's height and width.
Change `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dp_100), getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dp_100));`