# How to center ImageView in GridLayout?

Tags: android, imageview, android-gridlayout

I have a full screen grid layout with 8 rows of 7 ImageView.
I need all the rows centered without spaces between them (now I have as result the image I uploaded). The space must be only on the top and on the bottom. I already tried to find a solution on the Internet but I haven't found one.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:rowCount="8"
        android:columnCount="7"
        >
        <!-- ROW 1-1 -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/cellR1-1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dl"
            />
        <!-- ROW 1-2 -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/cellR1-2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dl"
            />
        <!-- ROW ... -->
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried as solution to set all the ImageViews height same as the width but my code didn't worked:

```
void setGrid(){
    //setting the cell height as the cell widht
    int imagWidth = cell[0][0].getLayoutParams().width;
    for(int r=0;r<rowCount;r++)
        for(int c=0;c<columnCount;c++) {
            cell[r][c].getLayoutParams().height = imagWidth;
            cell[r][c].requestLayout();
        }
}
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: There is something you know.I'm sure you can do with gridLayout. How about recyclerview ?. You need to search recyclerview and GridLayoutManager. You can some answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Comment: You've stated what you desire to achieve- but what is your code producing right now? That way we can try to fix it.

Comment: the image i uploaded. If you are referring to the code that i wrote to fix it changes nothing(see image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager like below:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 7);
            YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter();
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            int spacing = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16,
                    Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
                @Override
                public void getItemOffsets(@NotNull Rect outRect, @NotNull View view, @NotNull RecyclerView parent, @NotNull RecyclerView.State state) {

                    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == Objects.requireNonNull(parent.getAdapter()).getItemCount() - 1) {
                        outRect.bottom = spacing;
                    }
                    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
                        outRect.top = spacing;
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Other solution is:**
Instead of adding padding to both the top and bottom items, You can just add the padding to the top and bottom of your RecyclerView and set the `clipToPadding` attribute to `false`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to you, use the RecyclerView instead of GridLayout

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 7); // 7 means how many column you want you can change according to your requirement.
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
```