# Center RecycleView in Parent - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am following a [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the) on grid layout. In particular, I am replicating Suragch's answer.

The code itself is working fine, except I would like to center the RecyclerView in the activity.

I've tried

```
android:gravity="center"
```

and

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

on both the RelativeLayout AND RecyclerView, but neither works.

Also, I would like to eliminate the gaps between each column. Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: You should try adding gravity in adapter of your recyclerView, Please check my answer for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_centerInParent=true` into `<RecyclerView>`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me :(

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why should he?.

Comment: Please send your layouts

Comment: Cause this is for relative layout that he used

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your parent Layout

If its RelativeLayout then

`android:layout_centerHorizontal=true` in RecyclerView

if its LinearLayout then

`android:layout_gravity=center_horizontal` in RecyclerView

One more interesting thing you can do in Adapter

the main parent Layout in adapter

try doing this

`android:gravity=center_horizontal` in main layout of adapter