# Simplest way to have square images in grid layout with zoom in / zoom out ability in Android

Tags: android, image, layout, grid, zooming

**What layout that can display grid and allow to zoom in / zoom out do you recommend?** I'm looking for simplest possible solution.

I want to display a grid of sqaure images (number of columns and rows will differ and depend on user's earlier input) and I want them to be scalable. For example: think about Sudoku where each box is single image. I want user to zoom in and zoom out to this images. After clicking on one of boxes a method will replace some images with different ones.

Comment: Do you want the image to open separately and then zoom it or you want to zoom it within the Grid ?

Comment: Zoom it within the grid. Grid is not changing, user just can have a closer look at it.

Comment: You can use the zoom libraries available for android, here is one of them :

https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout

Comment: and to have your images in Grid View, you can use RecyclerView, use this example :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the