# Make RecyclerView faster

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to the android backend. In my application, I need to show  the data as in the photo. These are blocks 200x200 and more. Each block  is divided by 10x10. I used RecyclerView in another RecyclerView to get  this view, but it is slow. How to make it faster? I used part loading (adapter.notifyDataSetChanged) but scrolling working bad [image: Recyclerv]

Comment: Perhaps instead of recycler view inside a recycler view try using a GridLayoutManager... see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Comment: Are you making a lot of logic in the RecyclerView adapter? if so you should do that logic before, and in the adapter just simply display the views

Comment: Thanks to all for the help