# Problem with filling 5th column in GridLayout

Tags: android, xml, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

When I add the 5th column, the button with the number 5 half crawls out of the screen. When I add value to the buttons: android:layout_columnWeight="1", then the button with number 1 is stretched out of the screen.

How can I fit all 5 columns on the screen?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:columnCount="5">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="4"/>
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you try this in Llinearlayout then it will fit correct in the screen.If it is just a Button

Comment: reduce `android:textSize` .  GridLayout mandatory ?

Comment: it will be like calculator keys.

Answer (score 0):

set android:layout_width="match_parent" in GridLayout

Comment: better way is to use recyclerview with Grid layout manager like this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"

            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"

            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"

            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"

            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"

            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No, it will be a spaghetti code, if I add 14 buttons, it will be a mess