# In Recycler View, converting from a LinearLayoutManger to GridLayoutManager makes no difference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have an Android app using a recyclerView and a LinearLayoutManager. I was under the impression that changing the LinearLayoutManager to GridLayoutManager (see the commented line below and the following line) will simply give me a grid. But nothing changes and I still see the linear list, one item per row, and one column.

```
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_setup_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    adapter = new ItemSetupRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), kids);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can someone please let me know if there are other areas I need to change before I see the grid?

Here is the xml for the recyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/feed_recycle_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="74dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at this, maybe you are missing a step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Comment: can you share your xml?

Comment: @ChintanSoni I just did. Thanks

Comment: It seems you setup for item_setup_recycler_view, not your XML you post feed_recycle_view

Answer (score 0):

Use this like this.
In your .xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In  your code.

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3);

gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```

then give this to your recyclerView.

Or you can do with one line:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add orientation and direction of the list

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from @Công Hải I realized the change I was doing was the only change needed. The issue was I made the change on the wrong recycleView in my app. Once I modified the right recycleView everything worked as expected.