# Custom Android WeekView with vertical scroll to select cellules

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a custom weekView (Take a look on the image), I used a tabLayout inside a scrollView but i cannot implement the vertical scroll.
Can you suggest How to do it ?

1. How to do the vertical scroll ?
2. How to get the selected cells?

[image: Week View]

Comment: You can use a recylerview with a gridlayoutmanager:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Comment: How to select cellules with vertical scroll ?

Comment: Sorry, what is cellules? Recyclerview provides vertical scroll by default. Using a layout manager you can display its items as a list or a grid. So in your case you will maybe use a grid layout manager to display items like a grid.

Comment: I want to select for exapmle 4 items together by a vertical slide , How to implement it ?

Comment: In that case you have to implement a click listener. The Recyclerview uses an adapter to populate its grid. This adapter can be used to define a clicklistener method for each element in your grid. So when user clicks on an item in the grid, the click listener can be used to capture the event and mark that element as selected.