# How can I create like this?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create like this?

[image: screenshot]

I can't create this.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587169/7626390

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Very rarely do people just simply write code for you. We'd like to see you put some effort into your code and display it in the question. Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to see how.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with putting that in your `MainActivity.java` (I made some `Strings` as data for saving time):

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GridView gridView;
String [] yourData = {"Data1","Data2", "Data3", "Data4", "Data 5", "Data6","Data7", "Data8", "Data9", "Data10", "Data11", "Data12"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.GridView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, yourData);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Now you define the `GridView` in your `activity_main.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:id="@+id/GridView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Don't forget to put that into your `build.gradle(:app)` folder under `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
```

That's the result you will get:

[image: The result]

Cheers and try that with your `ImageView`, `CardView` or `ImageButton` instead of my `Strings`. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout) (Except for the top row, which is called `Toolbar` or `ActionBar`).