# Best way to make thumbnails for app gallery

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, thumbnails, android-glide

I'm working on a simple gallery app. I'm wondering what's the best way to create and dsiplay thumbnails. I was thinking about using `ThumbnailUtils`, making thumbnail for new pictures and then store it in app data storage as I assume that doing it every time when user displays all images isn't efficient. Though I'm not so sure what's better memory-wise. To load an image into `ImageView` which is part of `RecyclerView` item I'm using Glide. I don't know if `.thumbnail(...)` does what I want so I think I need to create thumbnails myself. Could someone show me the correct way to do this? I want the app to load quickly so it's obvious I can't load full resolution images to recycler.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for your result is to use the `GridLayout`. I wrote an answer yesterday how to achieve that [Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149371/how-can-i-create-like-this/67151348#67151348). Take a look. Cheers!

Comment: I'm not concerned about layout - I'm wondering what's the best way performance-wise to deal with thumbnails...