# I need to change the layoutManager property of the RecyclerView to GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I'm taking an online android studio course and im stuck with this task.

- Change the layoutManager property of the RecyclerView to GridLayoutManager.
- Change the column count to 3.
- Change the adapter layout to visualize data in a grid.

https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-affirmations-app-solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587169/12005280 This will answer your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:spanCount="3"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:listitem="here_your_item_layout"/>
```

Hope this helps you.

If this helps you then make answer correct and give up vote.

Thanks!!