# How to divide recyclerview in different views for showing image

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments

[image]

How to divide recyclerview  in different  views  for showing image

How to divide recyclerview  in different  views  for showing image

Comment: Have you tried on your own? What was wrong with the output? please provide some research.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack overflow, please add more details so we can help you. See here for more details on how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think your problem is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)

Answer (score 0):

Building that with the RecyclerView can be a little bit complicated. I would recommend you a library called **Epoxy**.

https://proandroiddev.com/building-complex-screens-in-a-recyclerview-with-epoxy-97845e51f4da